# html5sql - Can't seem to connect to my DB

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sqlite, web-storage

I'm using html5sql.com for doing html5 DB stuff :o)
- Really a great module...

However, I got stuck!

At my index.html/index.js I create my database and tables in it.

```
try {
        html5sql.openDatabase("com.dynamicvenues.fairkeyMobile.db","Questionnaire",3*1024*1024);
        html5sql.process(
                [
                 "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Questionnaire (uid INTEGER, json TEXT, hash TEXT);",
                 "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Answers (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, visitor_id TEXT, json TEXT);"
                ],
                function(){
                     console.log("Success Creating Tables");
                 },
                 function(error, statement){
                     console.error("Error: " + error.message + " when processing " + statement);
                 }        
        )
    } catch(error) {
        alert("Database create failed: "+error.message);
    }
```

And further in the same page I populate one table with data:

```
jQuery.get(serverHttp+"json.php?exhibitorID="+exhibitorID, function(data){
        var html = $(data).map(function() {
            return $(this).html();
        });
        var jsonStr = html[0];
        var exhibitorID = html[1];
        var hashStr = html[2];

        var SQL = "INSERT INTO Questionnaire (uid, json, hash) VALUES ("+exhibitorID+",'"+jsonStr+"','"+hashStr+"')";
        try {
            html5sql.process(SQL,
                    function(){
                        console.log('Inserted 1 row!');
                    },
                    function(){
                        console.error("Error: " + error.message + " when processing " + statement);
                    }
            )
        } catch(error) {
            alert("Query failed: "+error);
        }
```

Now, in a different page called questionnaire.html/questionnaire.js I'm trying to retrieve the data I stored in the table Questionnaire.

```
html5sql.process(
            ["SELECT * FROM Questionnaire;"],
            function(transaction, results, rowsArray){
                for(var i = 0; i < rowsArray.length; i++){
                    var uid = rowsArray[i].uid;
                    var json = rowsArray[i].json;
                    var hash = rowsArray[i].hash;
                    console.log("Retrieved rows: "+uid+" - "+json+" "+hash);
                }
                console.log("Done selecting data");
            },
            function(error, statement){
                console.error(error.message+" Occured while processing: "+statement);
            }
       );
```

What am I doing wrong???

Regards,
Daniel

Comment: Which browser are you using to test that? Be aware that only specific browser had implemented that feature before it was canceled. It seems that http://html5sql.com/ is using the Web SQL Database, a local SQL Database that no longer maintained by the W3C: ["Beware. This specification is no longer in active maintenance and the Web Applications Working Group does not intend to maintain it further."](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webdatabase/)

Comment: Solved!
Inserted: html5sql.openDatabase("com.dynamicvenues.fairkeyMobile.db","Questionnaire",3*1024*1024);
Before html5sql.process() at questionnaire.js...

Btw. this is for an Android App I'm building with Phonegap/Cordova

Comment: Then [post that as answer instead of a comment](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) and accept it. "To be crystal clear, it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged."

Comment: Since I'm new here, I can't answer my own question for the next 8 hours :(
Sorry

Comment: There, you should be able to post your answer now :)

Answer (score 1):

Solved! Inserted: `html5sql.openDatabase("com.dynamicvenues.fairkeyMobile.db","Questionnaire",3*102‌​4*1024);` Before `html5sql.process()` at questionnaire.js